# Passing mixin(s) within the view helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In Ember, we are using a lot the view helper within templates. I was wondering, if there is an easy way to pass mixin to an Ember.View class when the helper is getting executed (View is getting created).

Something like http://jsbin.com/ekuxal/2/edit

Example of a template:

```
{{view Ember.TextField mixins="App.Console"}}
```

Example of the Mixin:

```
App.Console = Ember.Mixin.create({
   didInsertElement: function(){
     this._super();
     console.log('from the mixin');
   }
});
```

*from the mixin* will be logged into the console.

Does it make sense to have something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Logging is just to give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view this requirement makes no sense to me.  Why? **Mixins are used when extending classes, since they are a way of  realizing multiple inheritance.** So they are used during data and logic modeling. **And the view helper is used for instantiating objects of a view class.** I think, it would be possible to do by writing a custom helper and use **createWithMixins()** within it. But it seems to be confusing to do such things in the template.

Can you clarify your requirement a bit more? Is it really just about logging?

**Update: Implementation Proposal**

I read throught the [source code of the view helper](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/view.js#L150) to evaluate wether this is possible. This is not out of the box functionality of Ember, but it might be possible by overwriting some logic in the Ember View helper.

Assume you have this template:

```
{{view App.YourView mixin="App.YourMixin"}}
```

The most important for the helper is the instance Ember.ViewHelper, which contains the logic to be modified. One could try to reopen it and modify the relevant parts like this:

```
var EmberHandlebars = Ember.Handlebars;
EmberHandlebars.ViewHelper.reopen({
  helper: function(thisContext, path, options) {
    var inverse = options.inverse,
        data = options.data,
        view = data.view,
        fn = options.fn,
        hash = options.hash,
        newView;

    if ('string' === typeof path) {
      newView = EmberHandlebars.get(thisContext, path, options);
      Ember.assert("Unable to find view at path '" + path + "'", !!newView);
    } else {
      newView = path;
    }

    // NEW CODE FOR MIXIN LOGIC
    if(hash.mixin){
      var newViewClass = newView; // newView should be the class App.YourView here
      var yourMixin = Ember.get(hash.mixin); //get the Mixin by name
      var newViewInstance = newView.createWithMixins(yourMixin); //create the view with mixin
      newView = newViewInstance; // assign the view to the variable where the rest of the logic is expecting it
    }

    Ember.assert(Ember.String.fmt('You must pass a view to the #view helper, not %@ (%@)', [path, newView]), Ember.View.detect(newView) || Ember.View.detectInstance(newView));

    var viewOptions = this.propertiesFromHTMLOptions(options, thisContext);
    var currentView = data.view;
    viewOptions.templateData = options.data;
    var newViewProto = newView.proto ? newView.proto() : newView;

    if (fn) {
      Ember.assert("You cannot provide a template block if you also specified a templateName", !get(viewOptions, 'templateName') && !get(newViewProto, 'templateName'));
      viewOptions.template = fn;
    }

    // We only want to override the `_context` computed property if there is
    // no specified controller. See View#_context for more information.
    if (!newViewProto.controller && !newViewProto.controllerBinding && !viewOptions.controller && !viewOptions.controllerBinding) {
      viewOptions._context = thisContext;
    }

    currentView.appendChild(newView, viewOptions);
  } 
});
```

**Note:** I could not yet test this logic myself.
**Update: Tested it successfully!**

Comment: Not for logging. Logging was just to give an example.

Comment: Let's say I have an autocomplete Mixin, I would like to easily mixin it with a Ember.TextField like `{{view Ember.TextField mixins="App.Autocomplete"}}` and `{{view Ember.TextField mixins="App.Autocomplete,App.AnotherMixin",App.AndAnotherMixin"}}` could work as well.

Comment: Thanks @mavilein! However, I decide to stick with the default view helper implementation. I still prefer creating new classes instead of pushing mixins with my template. My main reason > testing! It is easier to test against real classes.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would extend Ember's TextField view to create a custom view of your own and add the mixin to where you extend the view in the javascript. For example:

TEMPLATE:

```
{{view 'MyTextField'}} // Custom view that extends Ember.textField
```

VIEW:

```
App.MyTextFieldView = Em.TextField.extend(App.MyMixin, { // Add your mixin to Ember's TextField view here
    // Any further view code here (optional because this view already has all the functions of Ember's text field view and you've mixed in your other functionality in the line above).
});
```

MIXIN:

```
App.MyMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
    // Your mixin code here
});
```